# How to prove $l^3(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have a small confusion,i know how to prove $l^2(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space but i am not getting any idea to prove $l^3(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space.

Vector space is defined as

[image: Vector space is Defined as]

Comment: How do you define this vector space?

Comment: @IanColey The definition is in the question.

Comment: Since it is a subset of a vector space - the space of all real sequences - you need to show that 1. it is nonempty ($0$ pretty obviously belongs to $l^3(\mathbb{R})$), 2. scalar multiples of sequences in $l^3(\mathbb{R})$ belong to $l^3(\mathbb{R})$, this one is pretty obvious too, and finally, that the sum of two elements of $l^3(\mathbb{R}$ belongs to $l^3(\mathbb{R})$. The last one is not too difficult either, but not trivial.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know this axioms,Just in case how can i use Triangular inequality here ?!

Comment: @Jp when I commented, the definition wasn't there, so I'm glad it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-negativity and other norm properties are trivial to prove. The one which may be difficult is the triangle inequality.

To prove the triangle inequality for $\ell^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ (the cases for $p=1,\infty$ are trivial), you should know the following:

1. Young's inequality: For $a,b>0$, $1<p,q<\infty$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$,
   $$ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q}$$.
2. Holder's inequality: for $1 \leq p , q \leq \infty$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, $x \in \ell^p$, $y \in \ell^q$, 
   $$ \sum_i |x_i y_i| \leq ||x||_p ||y||_q$$
   (this is proved by a simple application of Young's inequality. Note for $p=q=2$, you get Cauchy-Schwarz. For $p=1$, this is a straightforward result since $q=\infty$)

Now, you can prove the triangle inquality in $\ell^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ (try $p=1,p=\infty$ on your own):
$\sum_i |x_i+y_i|^p = \sum_i |x_i+y_i|^{p-1} |x_i+y_i| \leq \sum_i (|x_i+y_i|^{p-1} |x_i| + |x_i+y_i|^{p-1} |y_i|)$.

Now, apply Holder's inequality to both terms to get the upper bound $(\sum_i |x_i+y_i|^{(p-1)q})^{1/q} (\sum_i |x_i|^p)^{1/p} + (\sum_i |x_i+y_i|^{(p-1)q})^{1/q} (\sum_i |y_i|^p)^{1/p}$. Now, divide through by $(\sum_i |x_i+y_i|^p)^{1/q}$ and note that $(p-1)q=p$ and $1-\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}$ to get the result that $(\sum_i |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ is indeed a norm.

Comment: Note that when you say "divide through by $(\sum_i |x_i+y_i|^p)^{1/q}$" you are assuming that such sum is finite, which is precisely what you want to prove. Because of that is that in the proof of Minkowski's Inequality you first need to do the step I did, and then you prove the inequality as you did.

Comment: Yes, this answers (b), while you answered (a).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\sum_n|x_n|^3<\infty$, $\sum_n|y_n|^3<\infty$. The key inequality is 
$$
|a+b|^3\leq(|a|+|b|)^3\leq(2\max\{|a|,|b|\})^3=8\max\{|a|^3,|b|^3\}\leq 8(|a|^3+|b|^3).
$$

Then
$$
\sum_n|x_n+y_n|^3\leq 8\,\sum_n|x_n|^3+8\,\sum_n|y_n|^3<\infty.
$$